# Set find member vs. using find on list

Tags: c++, find, set, std

Since the items in a Standard Library set container are sorted, will using the find member on the set, in general, perform faster than using the find algorithm on the same items in a sorted list?

Since the list is linear and the set is often implemented using a sorted tree, it seems as though the set-find should be faster.

Comment: Yes, but [`std::binary_search`](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/binary_search.html) on a sorted list may be faster still.

Comment: @larsmans: important note, `binary_search` returns whether the element is contained or not, not an iterator. Also, I really doubt it will be faster. On a sorted vector, why not, but on a list you still have a **linear** walk, even though you only have `O(log N)` comparisons.

Comment: @larsmans: No, it is not. Since list has no random access iterators, the "jumping around" needs a lot of time. A quick bench on gcc 4.6 here shows that for searching a number in 1500 integers, set takes 0.001 seconds, while linear search on list takes 406 times more, and binary search on a list takes 1338 times as much as the set.

Comment: @PlasmaHH: Sorry, I confused lists and arrays. Been writing too much Python lately :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With a linked list, even a sorted one, finding an element is `O(n)`. A set can be searched in `O(log n)`. Therefore yes, finding an element in a set is asymptotically faster.

A sorted array/vector can be searched in `O(log n)` by using binary search. Unfortunately, since a linked list doesn't support random access, the same method can't be used to search a sorted linked list in `O(log n)`.

Comment: Note: You will have `O(log n)` comparisons (which is usually what is counted for sort/search) but `O(n)` (at least) moves.

Answer (score 2):

It's actually in the standard: `std::set::find()` has complexity `O(log n)`, where `n` is the number of elements in the set. `std::find()` on the other hand is linear in the length of the search range.

If your generic search range *happens* to be sorted and has random access (e.g. a sorted vector), then you can use `std::lower_bound()` to find an element (or rather a position) efficiently.

Note that `std::set` comes with its own member-`lower_bound()`, which works the same way. Having an insertion position may be useful even in a `set`, because `insert()` with a *correct* hint has complexity `O(1)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can generally expect a `find` operation to be faster on a `Set` than on a `List`, since lists are linear access (O(n)), while sets may have near-constant access for HashSets (O(1)), or logarithmic access for TreeSets (O(log n)).

Answer (score 0):

`set::find` has a complexity of O(log(n)), while `std::find` has a complexity of O(n). This means that `std::set::find()` is *asymptotically* faster than `std::find(std::list)`, but that doesn't mean it is faster for any particular data set, or for any particular search.

Answer (score 0):

I found this article helpful on the topic. http://lafstern.org/matt/col1.pdf

You could reconsider your requirements for just a "list" vs. a "set". According to that article, if your program consists primarily of a bunch of insertions at the start, and then after that, only comparisons to what you have stored, then you are better off with adding everything to a vector, using std::sort (vector.begin(), vector.end()) once, and then using lower_bound. In my particular application, I load from a text file a list of names when the program starts up, and then during program execution I determine if a user is in that list. If they are, I do something, otherwise, I do nothing. In other words, I had a single discrete insertion phase, then I sorted, then after that I used std::binary_search (vector.begin(), vector.end(), std::string username) to determine whether the user is in the list.